# xor and color inversion?

Tags: algorithm

What is the inversion of colors algorithm ? How can we implement this?

For example

```
Black->White
Blue->Yellow
```

Comment: Which colour space? RGB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do this:

```
RInv = 255 - R
GInv = 255 - G
BInv = 255 - B
```

which can be done with XOR as follows:

```
RInv = R xor 255
GInv = G xor 255
BInv = B xor 255
```

The `xor` works because we want the sum of R and RInv to be equal to 255:

```
RInv = 255 - R
=> RInv  + R = 255
```

and, since a `xor` on binary numbers is an addition over the Galois field mod 2, we get:

```
C = A xor B
=> C xor B = A xor B xor B = A
RInv = 255 xor R
RInv xor R = 255
```

Comment: And although the two are equivalent, xor was used traditionally because it was faster on older CPUs.